# Resilience4j Circuit breaker using fallback

Tags: java, spring-boot

My service has to call another service. But if that service is down, it has to call the fallback URL of the same service. It's like the service is deployed in two data centers. If everything is fine call the one in primary DC if the primary is down called the one in secondary one.

I am trying to achieve this using a circuit breaker in resilience4j. 
The requirement is like

1. service in primary DC is up -> call primary service
2. service in primary DC is down, service in secondary DC is up -> don't call primary service but call only secondary service.
3. service in primary DC is down, service in secondary DC is down -> don't call any service and return default response.

Identification of a service, if it is up or down can be done if the service is failing x% in last y seconds.

Can you help how should I do this? I am using Resilience4j and spring-boot in my application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the support provided for [Vavr's `Try` and use `recover` method](https://javadoc.io/doc/io.vavr/vavr/0.9.2/io/vavr/control/Try.html#recover-java.util.function.Function-)

```
circuitBreaker
    .decorateTrySupplier(() -> Try.ofSupplier(() -> "Call Service 1."))
    .get()
    .recover(CallNotPermittedException.class, exception -> "Call Service 2")
    .get();
```

Comment: this will always call service1. I don't want service1 to be called when it is failing for a duration.

Comment: Edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: @warrior107 is there something else you are looking for?

Comment: I think this may help me. Will mark the answer as accept after trying. thank you

Comment: Question: If I want to chain multiple recoveries, can I do like this
`circuitBreaker. decorateTrySupplier(...).get().recover(...).recover(...).get();`

Comment: Yes you can however only the first `Try` has the circuit breaker applied, so subsequent `recover` failures would not be guarded by the circuit breaker, if you want that you would need the again decorate the `Try` with the circuit breaker.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. For the recover to be guarder by circuit breaker, would that be a different circuit breaker?

Comment: Ideally yes since the it would enter the first recover only when the circuit breaker is open (We are recovering only on CallNotPermittedException), so if you again use the same circuit breaker it is already open, and no recovery will actually happen.

Comment: thanks for helping me follow the right approach to solve my problems.